# How to Sum the generated Columns rdlc file?

Tags: c#, sum, rdlc

I am new to windows desktop application development.

I am creating a report which has a table.

```
Sr | Description | HSNCode | Qty | Rate | Amount
```

Amount is generated by using `<<Exp>>` like `Fields!Qty.Value*Fields!Rate.Value`

Now I want to display the Gross Amount by getting the Sum of the Amount field.

I tried `Sum(Fields!Qty.Value, "DataSet1")*Sum(Fields!Rate.Value, "DataSet1")` but not working.

How to do so?
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method in the code of the report properties that calculates the amount storing this value in a private field. For each row this calculation the total is shown and summed with the internal  value.

a second method than retreives the total value resetting the private field to 0.

(code in rdlc is in vb thats why I don't hava an example)

example in c#:(must be VB!!!)

```
private decimal total;

public decimal CalculateRowTotal(int qty, decimal rate)
{
    var rowtotal = qty * rate;
    total = total + rowtotal;
    return rowtotal;
}  

public decimal showTotal()
{
    decimal returnvalue = total;
    total = 0m;
    return returnvalue;
}
```

in your rdlc u use this global methods.